# How to create ssr in reactjs

Tags: reactjs, react-native

I'm trying to code a date picker using ReactJS but I don't know how to create a dynamic table that displays the actual month days every time I hit previous or next buttons. Here's my code: // Next step I need to add a matrix of weekdays (1..31) and check each month existing ...

Answer (score 0):

I wouldn't reinvent a wheel unless it's unavoidable.
There are multiple date pickers that can be used out of the box:
E.g.:

- https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-date-picker
- https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-datepicker
- https://react-day-picker.js.org/

But that's only if you just need any picker. If you **must** create a custom one, then this doesn't help.